# JVM and Java Process

Tags: java, process, jvm

This might be a very basic query about Java JVM. If I've brought up 2 separate programs using a bash script, 2 processes are running and I can see the processes using ps -ef command.

Does that mean they are running as 2 separate JVM's? I have this query, since I can see that the parent process id (PPID) is same for both the processes.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
Does that mean they are running as 2 separate JVM's?
```

Yes.  The 'java' command starts a JVM.

Comment: What does the PPID tell us then? Doesn't same PPID means these 2 processes are part of same process?

Comment: PPID is parent process id.  Means that the two processes have the same parent, the shell that's interpreting your script.  (Aside: "process that's part of a process" does not mean anything)

Answer (score 1):

Yes, both are two completely separate JVMs running as native OS processes. This includes garbage collector, JIT compiler, and all the other usual stuff.

Each OS process has a parent, if nothing else, then it's the "init" process that starts as the first thing when the OS is booting.

Btw. Java command line tools, notably `jcmd` are really good for exploring java/jvm processes on your machine - e.g. you can just type `jcmd` to list all of them; type `jcmd <PID> help` to check list of available commands for specific process.

`htop` is another good tool to explore process hierarchy.